# How do I remove the "admin todo tour" from a new Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I've created a new Facebook page and after some days it keeps displaying the "admin todo tour" , which among other things shows me a message telling me to create a post for reaching 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000 etc fans. It's always there displayed in the url bar. I assume there is something else to do, otherwise it wouldnt be displaying a "to do" tour mode which doesnt show me what to do to remove it, and which sporadically tells me to create a message telling the fans we've reached a new amount of followers.

How do I remove the "admin todo tour" from a new Facebook page?

Comment: did you have any solution, how to get rid of this shitty "admin_todo_tour"?

Comment: Nope, as a matter of fact the page has over a million fans already and I still have the "admin_todo_tour"

Comment: is crazy, facebook, I don't say about annoying facebook popups that removes the focus away when you are trying to write a message... so you are suddenly writing in another textbox...

Answer (score 1):

I used AdBlocker to remove the intrusive facebook div, so now I am happy with a clear page.